# Xcode 11 Unit Test: Devices with iOS 12.* are not listed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I'm trying to run my unit tests with iOS 12.* (I already downloaded the simulators), but Xcode doesn't display the devices in the drop down view where all available devices are listed. I even tried to add additional simulators, but only devices with iOS 13 are listed in the drop down view. What am I doing wrong?

Note: The projects iOS Deployment Target is 12.0.

**Picture 1:** These are all iOS 13 capable devices:

[image]

**Picture 2:** Devices with iOS 12 & iOS 12.2 are available as you can see:

[image]

---

**Solution**: You need to set `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` explicitly to iOS 12.0 for the unit test target. My mistake was that I only set the deployment target for the project.

Comment: Check the deployment target.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov something weird happened. The Deployment Target was already set to 12.0. When I explicitly selected 12.0 again all devices were shown to me in the drop down window, but when I try to run my unit tests I get this warning: Title: "The run destination iPhone 8 Plus is not valid for tests you have chosen to perform." Message: "Please select a run destination which supports the tests that you wish to perform."

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Update: OMG it worked! I had to set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET explicitly for the unit test target. This solved the problem.

Comment: This solved the problem for me as well.

Comment: @AndrewRomanov Took me some time to find where to actually change that setting for the unit tests, as I am still very new to build settings. In Xcode 11, in the project editor, select Build Settings. On the line you just clicked, on the left side, the target of the build settings is shown. Click on the dropdown arrow, and select the unit test target, then go down on the page to the "Deployment" section, and adjust to the desired iOS version.

Comment: I've added answer with instruction.

Answer (score 2):

To change deployment target, tap to your project file in the Navigator. 
Select General tab, in a section "Deployment target" you can find a Target and a Device: 
[image]

Or select Build Settings tab and find iOS Deployment Target setting:
[image]

You should select appropriate deployment targets for all targets in your application. (For example your application can support iOS 7 and have deployment target as 7.0, but extension in your application or test target can support only >= iOS 8.0 and deployment target should be selected for 8.0 for that targets)